# jquery plugin change $('#somediv').foo to $.foo

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a jquery plugin and its working well but it needs an outer->outer wrapper #id (#somediv) ie:

```
$('#somediv').foo({
     wrap : 'example',
     one  : 'red',
     two  : 'blue',
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="somediv">
 <<div id="example">
<!-- Do stuff -->
 </div>
</div>
```

to me the outer->outer wrapper (#somediv) is not needed and would like to be able to remove the need for it and simply have one wrapper which is actually the `wrap : 'example',` option and call the plugin options like this:

```
$.foo({
     wrap : 'example',
     one  : 'red',
     two  : 'blue',
  });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="example">
<!-- Do stuff -->
 </div>
```

so as the title says how can I change change `$('#somediv').foo` to `$.foo`?

**Basic plugin layout:**

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.foo = function(opts) {
        var defaults = {
         wrap : 'example',
         one  : 'red',
         two  : 'blue'
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        return this.each(function() {

//  Do stuff

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

As usual all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning it to `jQuery.fn` assign to straight to `jQuery`.

You can also use `extend()` like...

```
$.extend({
   foo: function() { ... }
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure how tbh, I've added the basic plugin layout i'm using so you can see what I have so far.